# Aggregate data in one column based on values/factors in four another columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have a data frame in my R script that looks something like this:

```css
> head(species.prop)
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

   year month  area species catch.p
  (dbl) (dbl) (chr)   (chr)   (dbl)
1  1998     4  VI      hom    17.25
2  1998     5  VII     pil    17.25
3  2000     4  VI      hom    40.25
4  1998     4  IV      hom    27.60
5  2000     1  VII     pil    46.00
6  1998     4  VI      pil     8.05
```

What I would like to do is alter the data frame so that it will give me the sum of the catch.p per species per area per month per year. The results should be a data frame like the one above with all the same columns headings.

I have tried aggregate:

```
> aggregate(catch.p~area~species~month~year, species.prop,sum)
```

Error in model.frame.default(formula = catch.p ~ area ~ species ~ month ~  : 
  object is not a matrix

> 

but could not figure out how to apply this function here properly

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a million!!

Comment: Try `aggregate(catch.p~area+species+month+year, species.prop,sum)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dplyr package in R.

```
species.prop %>% group_by(species, area, month, year) %>% summarise(catch.p = sum(catch.p))
```

With the data given, the outcome looks like

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: species, area, month [?]

```
  species   area month  year catch.p
   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
1     hom     IV     4  1998   27.60
2     hom     VI     4  1998   17.50
3     hom     VI     4  2000   40.25
4     pil     VI     4  1998    8.05
5     pil    VII     1  2000   46.00
6     pil    VII     5  1998   17.50
```

But to show you how this works, I changed row 6 in the original data submitted to  Area = VII and month = 5, and it looks like

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: species, area, month [?]

```
  species   area month  year catch.p
   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
1     hom     IV     4  1998   27.60
2     hom     VI     4  1998   17.50
3     hom     VI     4  2000   40.25
4     pil    VII     1  2000   46.00
5     pil    VII     5  1998   25.55
```